# Write bytes to file at a specific offset

Tags: file, dart, byte

Basically, i want to write bytes to file at a specific position.
I can't seem to find any possible solutions :/

I tried using openWrite() IOSink, to be exact addStream(), but that still doesnt let me skip to the specific byte in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a [`RandomAccessFile`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/RandomAccessFile-class.html), which you can obtain via [`File.open`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/open.html)/[`openSync`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/openSync.html).

From there, you can use [`RandomAccessFile.setPosition`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/RandomAccessFile/setPosition.html)/[`setPositionSync`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/RandomAccessFile/setPositionSync.html) and then use one of the various methods to write bytes (e.g. [`writeFrom`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/RandomAccessFile/writeFrom.html)/[`writeFromSync`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/RandomAccessFile/writeFromSync.html)).